# How to wrap overflow text in Folium GeoJson popup?

Tags: html, leaflet, folium

I am adding a GeoJSON layer to a folium map. I am setting it up to show popup using fields of GeoJSON, but one of the fields is a really long URL. I want it to be wrapped, not overflow. How can I achieve that?

My popup object:

```py
popup=folium.features.GeoJsonPopup(
    fields=list(layer.popup_fields.keys()),
    aliases=list(layer.popup_fields.values()),
    style=(
        "background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;"
    ),
)
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to your styles.

Comment: This did not work. Still the text is overflowing.

Comment: Oh? can you please try this `white-space: break-spaces;`

Comment: Can you share your notebook, please?

also please check the html popup https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bibmartin/folium/blob/issue288/examples/Popups.ipynb#Fancy-HTML-popup